# Permutação entre arrays em Java

Tags: java, array

Estou tentando criar um código que gere uma matriz de dados. Essa matriz consiste em todas as possibilidades entre determinados arrays.

Meus arrays são:

```
[Corretor, Clientes]
[Para Voce, Para sua Familia, Para Todos]
[Masculino, Feminino]
[Sim, Nao]
[Solteiro, Casado, Divorciado, Viuvo]
[Ate 4k, de 4k a 8k, de 8k a 12k, de 12k a 16k, acima de 16k]
[Essencial, Sob medida, Superior]
```

A partir disso, quero criar um código que gere todas as possibilidades entre esses arrays. Ou seja, ele pode me retornar um array, por exemplo, desta forma:

> **[Corretor, Para Voce, Masculino, Sim, Solteiro, Ate 4k, Essencial]**

Os códigos que fiz e estudei apenas me dão as possibilidades dentro de um array e não entre dois ou mais arrays.

```
public class Permutar {
    public static void permutar(int[] conjunto, int p) {
        if (p == 3) {
            System.out.printf("{%d, %d, %d}%n", conjunto[0], conjunto[1], conjunto[2]);
        } else {
            do {
                permutar(conjunto, p + 1);
                conjunto[p]++;
            } while (conjunto[p] < 3);
            conjunto[p] = 0;
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] conjunto = {0, 0, 0};
        permutar(conjunto, 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Supondo que seus arrays são esses:

```
String[] v1 = { "Corretor", "Clientes" };
String[] v2 = { "Para Voce", "Para sua Familia", "Para Todos" };
String[] v3 = { "Masculino", "Feminino" };
String[] v4 = { "Sim", "Nao" };
String[] v5 = { "Solteiro", "Casado", "Divorciado", "Viuvo" };
String[] v6 = { "Ate 4k", "de 4k a 8k", "de 8k a 12k", "de 12k a 16k", "acima de 16k" };
String[] v7 = { "Essencial", "Sob medida", "Superior" };
```

Uma maneira de gerar todas as combinações é usando recursão:

```
public void permutacoes(String[][] arrays, List<String[]> result, int indiceAtual, String combinacao) {
    if (indiceAtual == arrays.length) {
        // split para gerar um array
        result.add(combinacao.split(","));
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arrays[indiceAtual].length; i++) {
        permutacoes(arrays, result, indiceAtual + 1,
                    combinacao+ (combinacao.isEmpty() ? "" : ", ") + arrays[indiceAtual][i]);
    }
}
```

Basicamente, o `indiceAtual` indica em qual dos arrays estou atualmente. Para cada um deles, eu percorro-o e gero uma permutação indo para o array seguinte, e faço a concatenação do texto, usando as vírgulas para separar cada parte.

No final, terei a lista `result`, contendo todas as combinações, e aí basta percorrer esta lista para imprimir seus elementos.

Para usar este método, basta criar um novo array contendo os arrays originais, e chamá-lo passando zero como o índice inicial e a `String` vazia como a primeira combinação:

```
// array contendo todos os outros arrays
String[][] m = { v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7 };
List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
permutacoes(m, result, 0, "");
result.forEach(r -> System.out.printf("%s\n", Arrays.asList(r)));
```

Eu uso [`Arrays.asList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList-T...-) para transformar o array em lista, assim a saída fica desta forma:

```
[Corretor,  Para sua Familia,  Feminino,  Nao,  Viuvo,  acima de 16k,  Sob medida]
[Corretor,  Para sua Familia,  Feminino,  Nao,  Viuvo,  acima de 16k,  Superior]
[Corretor,  Para Todos,  Masculino,  Sim,  Solteiro,  Ate 4k,  Essencial]
[Corretor,  Para Todos,  Masculino,  Sim,  Solteiro,  Ate 4k,  Sob medida]
```

Mas claro que, uma vez tendo o array, você pode percorrê-lo e imprimir seus elementos da maneira que quiser.

---

#### Sem recursão

Se não quiser usar recursão, o jeito mais simples (e nesse caso, um pouco "feio") é usar vários loops aninhados, um para cada array:

```
List<String[]> result = new ArrayList<>();
for (String s1 : v1) {
    for (String s2 : v2) {
        for (String s3 : v3) {
            for (String s4 : v4) {
                for (String s5 : v5) {
                    for (String s6 : v6) {
                        for (String s7 : v7) {
                            result.add(new String[] { s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7 });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Neste caso, admito que não ficou um código muito bonito, pois virou uma variação do "hadouken de `if`'s":

[image]

Mas o resultado final é o mesmo.

Comment: uma duvida aqui, será que não daria para resolver com flatMap? fiquei curioso hahaha

Comment: @CezarCruz Se está falando do flatMap da API de streams, não vejo motivo para usar aqui. Mas se vc quiser, pode tentar e adicionar uma resposta, seria interessante ver outras soluções :-)

Comment: Na verdade eu não sei se é possivel, estou realmente curioso hahaha, se achar, coloco o link. obrigado.